# No components are editable in SiteEdit 2009

Tags: siteedit

We are facing a strange issue in SiteEdit. All the editable components are coming with a red block icon instead of pencil icon and we are not able to edit any of the component.
We have tried republishing the components and have also verified that the component exist on page (as mentioned in troubleshoot document).

We are using SiteEdit 2009 SP3 – Build 2.4.0.5426. We have applied all the hot-fixes for SiteEdit available on SDL Tridion World. Attached is the screen shot for the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the SiteEdit markup for this specific Component and the SiteEdit markup on the bottom of the Page?

Answer (score 3):

The red border is indicating that SiteEdit thinks the Component Presentation is not available on that Page.

This basically means there is a mismatch between the ID of the Page and the IDs of the Component and Component Templates as specified in your SiteEdit markup on the page.

Comment: Doesn't the same behavior happen when the Component Presentations are dynamic? If so: http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/siteedit-2009-dynamic-component-presentations.aspx

Comment: I think you are right, that might also be an issue indeed, but then they still should be editable right?

Comment: Only when marked as dynamic

Comment: There were two site edit tags at the bottom of the page. one for the page and one for the master page. after removing one it is working. We are still figuring out why there were two site edit tags.

Comment: SiteEdit most likely was looking at the wrong page in TCM. Since it couldn't find any of the Component Presentations on that page, it marked them as "Removed" (the red border and icon you show).